# Should I give my credit card number, expiry date and CVV to a hotel in order to receive a refund?

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, scams

I recently stayed in a hotel in Perth, WA. They charged my card for the room and added a security bond to be refunded after I leave. This was all debited from my UK credit card.

They now say that because the payment was made via "tap and  go" they don't have my card details and cannot make the refund. I must send them my card details.

They say that they require the card number, expiry date and CVV.

This sounds **very** dubious to me but what alternative do I have!?

Comment: The CVV is indeed suspicious; I don't think that it is needed for a refund.  Can you contact your bank for advice?

Comment: Contact your bank https://www.ratecity.com.au/credit-cards/articles/know-credit-card-refunds

Comment: I am relatively sure that the hotel does not even need the expiration date, but just the card number to refund and amount to your credit card.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I'm not sure: it is not about being technically possible, but also possible laws to make "money laundry" difficult. Else I could book with one stolen card, and later ask a refund (and the link is just on hotel system, so slower to intercept), and deny you ever booked or asked refund (there is no direct link, just possibly an *error* writing the numbers of a third person.

Comment: I recently had to get a refund from a trusted business, and they requested all the same information to issue the refund. My understanding is they CAN issue a refund without it, but that requires them to pull the original transaction. It's easier for them to just enter a new transaction with a negative amount

Comment: @Ezekiel so, to make their lives easier, you give them unrestricted access to your credit card? Doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: @paul They had already been given my card information to make the original charge, so I wasn't really giving them anything new. I'm not saying it's ideal, I'm just providing an example that corroborates the original question. With US credit cards there's little meaningful risk.

Comment: @Ezekiel surely you didn't give them all that information, unless you paid over the phone? Even then, that information should have been immediately destroyed after making the authorization to charge you.

Comment: @njzk2 Many stores still don't have customer facing point of sale devices, so they would've taken my credit card for a moment, like at most restaurants in the united states. They also would have my zip code, clearly listed on my invoice that they're using to charge me.

Your second point proves why they asked for it again. They did NOT have that information anymore, so the easiest way was to recollect it instead of reversing the original charge. I'm not saying they did it perfectly.

Comment: @Ezekiel you're pulling my leg, right? Any business without a point of sale I've seen only accepts cash. Any card transaction can be reversed by the seller, and they don't need anything except the reference to the transaction, which they really should have, even if only for their accounting

Comment: @njzk2 I mean they don't have a customer facing POS, not that they don't have one at all. Again, like a restaurant. You hand them the card and they swipe it on their computer.

Comment: @Ezekiel in a restaurant, I tap my card on the terminal, or I insert it in the machine and input my pin. Regardless, once the transaction is made, there is a reference to it, and that's the reference that you use to revert it.

Comment: @njzk2 Most sit-down restaurants in the US don't bring terminals to the table. I'm aware how it works in other countries. And yes, you're correct it SHOULD be handled better.